# How can I make my discord.py bot mentions someone mentioned in my message?

Tags: python, discord.py, mention

So I know that there is a similar question on stack overflow but it is for discord.js and I use discord.py so can someone tell me (also this is my first question on stack overflow)

Comment: Please refine your question & provide an examples of what you have tried. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some help with regard to asking questions. Otherwise im happy to help, just slightly confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so the above one is almost correct.
The solution is:

```
@client.command()
async def something(ctx, target:discord.Member = None):
    if target == None:
        await ctx.send("You didn't mention anyone!")
    
    else:
        await ctx.send(target.mention)
#whatever other code
```

so it's `target:discord.Member = None` instead of `target:discord.Member == None` and that async def thingy ofcourse :)

Answer (score 0):

(This is my first reply aswell!)

so lets say

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands #or command I can't remember)

#setup setting(on_ready.. etc)

@client.command(ctx, target:discord.Member == None) #CTX represents your command, target means your mentioned member

if target == None:
    await ctx.send("You didn't mention anyone!")
else:
    await ctx.send(target.mention)

#client run token
```

Comment: it's `target:discord.Memeber = None`

Comment: Wth how did I miss that ‍♂️‍♂️

Comment: It's ok NastyCore we all make small mistakes